# Active Directory - Get Manager account (from Distinguished Name)

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying to get the manager's account for a user account in active directory.

Here's the code I have..

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;


DirectoryContext directoryContext = new  DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, "MyDomain");
Domain domain = Domain.GetDomain(directoryContext);

// Find MY directory Entry
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(domain.GetDirectoryEntry())
{
    Filter = String.Format("(SAMAccountName={0})", "<my user id>")
};
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("manager");
DirectoryEntry userAccount = search.FindOne()?.GetDirectoryEntry();
```

As you can see, there's a property called *manager* that is requested and comes back as

*CN=**Manager Name**,OU=Employee,OU=United Kingdom, OU=CompantUsers, DC=MyDomain, DC=xxx,DC=zzzzz*

The *CN=**Manager Name*** is the full name, not the LoginID/*SAMAccountName* (as used when I searched for MY AD entry ... so how can I now find the AD entry for my manager

Answer (score 3):

Ahhh ... When you know the right question to ask then Google knows the answer ... I did not know that the *CN.....* string was known as a ***distinguishedName***

```
if (userAccount.Properties["manager"].Value != null)
{
  DirectorySearcher search2 = new DirectorySearcher(domain.GetDirectoryEntry())
  {
    Filter = string.Format("(distinguishedName={0})", userAccount.Properties["manager"].Value)
  };
  search2.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
  search2.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
  search2.PropertiesToLoad.Add("manager");
  DirectoryEntry mgrAcc = search2.FindOne()?.GetDirectoryEntry();
}
```